# Error with ui-sref

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting an error for the first ui-sref inside div with class="row episode-link" although the rest work correctly:

`Syntax Error: Token '}' not a primary expression at column 12 of the expression [{seriesId: }] starting at [}].`

The same ui-sref if put anywhere in the rest of the html structure works perfectly.

Unable to track the bug. Please Help.

```
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row episode-link">
                <a ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: {{show._id}}})">
                    <div class="col-md-12 guide">
                        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="float: right;"></span>
                        <h5>Episode Guide</h5>
                        <p>{{episodes.length}} episodes</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="seriesjumbo jumbotron">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 show-img-div align-items-center">
                                <img class="show-img" src="{{show.poster}}" alt="{{show.seriesName}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <h1>{{show.seriesName}}</h1>
                                <p class="episode-info"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>{{show.firstAired | date: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}}</span></p>
                                <p class="info">{{show.network}}  <span class="rating"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg star" aria-hidden="true"></i>  {{show.rating}}</span></p>
                                <p class="info"><em>{{show.airsDayOfWeek}}s, {{show.airsTime}} GMT </em></p>
                                <div class="cap">
                                    <span class="label label-default" ng-repeat="genre in show.genre">{{genre}}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="menus"><span class="fa fa-list"></span></div>
                                <div class="menus"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></div>
                                <div class="bookmark"><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span></div>
                                <div class="menus"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></div>
                                <div>
                                    <h3>Overview </h3>
                                    <p>{{show.overview}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <uib-tabset active="active">
                    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Episodes">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h5>Seasons</h5>
                                <ul class="season-list">
                                    <li ng-repeat="season in seasons | orderBy: '-valueOf()'"><a ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: {{show._id}}, season: {{season}}})">{{season}}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h5>Years</h5>
                                <ul class="season-list">
                                    <li ng-repeat="year in firstAired | orderBy:'-toString()'"><a ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: {{show._id}}, year: {{year}}})">{{year}}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Fan Arts">
                        <div ui-view="fan_arts"></div>
                    </uib-tab>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Why do you create the link like this `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: {{show._id}}, season: {{season}}})"` instead of `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: show._id, season: season})"`? What is the purpose of using this style, and not passing object for the parameters in the URL?

Comment: Does this `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: show._id})"` works?

Comment: Yes it works. I have a state defined with `url: 'series/:seriesId/episodes?season&year'`

Comment: the query parameters are optional in ui-router

Comment: `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: {{show._id}}, season: {{season}}})"` is beacuse I am using angular js for data binding.

Comment: So that's fine - If they are optional then don't include then and they url will be without them. If you need to include them use the following format: `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: show._id, year: year})"` (For example - This will create a link with only the year parameter and the value of the user will be whatever value in the `ngRepeat`. So you don't need to use `{{ expression }}` when passing parameters to `ui-sref`

Comment: Perhaps this will work: `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: '{{show._id}}', season: '{{season}}'})"`, but this should definitely work `ui-sref="app.episode({seriesId: show._id, season: season})"`

Comment: Thanks man. That works. You are a life-saver.

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck!